# How can I use easyslider in grails?

Tags: javascript, grails, easyslider

how can I implement easyslider 1.7 in grails? I know that you have to include the g:javascript tags, but how do I modify the code for this part:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true, 
            continuous: true,
            numeric: true
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

I am new to grails, and would really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: As I see, easyslider is completelly client side lib, seems that you don't need to do anything special to support Grails backend, probably you could use it just as usual. What and why you want to modify for this code sample?

Comment: Oh.. but when I used the original code, I didn't manage to get the slider to work when i ran my grails project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create application resources in `conf/ApplicationResources.groovy`.

```
modules = {
    'slider_resources' {
        resource url: 'css/slider.css'
        resource url: 'js/slider.js'
    }
}
```

Which can be easily included in your GSP files with:

```
<r:require module="slider_resources" />
```

To use this mechanism the resources plugin needs to be installed.

See http://grails.org/plugin/resources